# How to Save HTML userinput into a txt. file and Load the saved input into the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I've recently made a CharacterSheet for a game using HTML. The HTML file mainly consists out of the 
`<input type="text">`, `<input type="number">`, `<input type="checkbox">`, `<input type="radio">`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` tags to insert data. Is there a way to save all the inserted data into a txt. file and load it up into the HTML document upon startup of the HTML document?

In some other posts they had the problem that browsers didn't allow writing to a file as they saw it as a security issue. But as both the HTML and txt files are on my pc there shouldn't be a problem, i think.

Comment: you should consider using localstorage or cookies. although it isn't permanent..

Comment: No, there is no (easy/standard/without add ons) way to write to a file on the pc from a browser, regardless of where the html comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could allow the user to download a text file, then when they start the game upload it where you can parse it, but a better way is to just use the `localStorage` built into modern browsers. It will be stored permanently in the users browser until it's deleted.

```
localStorage.game = JSON.stringify({ score: 1 }) // put
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.game)) // get
```